# Correct usage of "to find oneself at daggers drawn with sb."

Tags: grammar, phrases, popular-refrains

I am looking into the usage of the phrase

> to find oneself at daggers drawn with sb.

It seems to require a person at the end of the phrase, but I would like to use it in the following way:

> and find yourself at daggers drawn with gentrification

In the meaning, that if you go there, as in a place, you will likely be engaged in heavy gentrification discussions. Can I use it this way? If not, what are alternatives?

Comment: Doesn't the phrase suggest that the object of *with* also has a dagger drawn?

Comment: Yes, but if wind can whisper through trees, why couldn't gentrification draw a dagger on someone or something? It's an example of *personification,* a common literary device.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more likely that you would write ***with** daggers drawn **at***?

Comment: @JimReynolds Perhaps *... at daggers drawn with the **gentry***

Comment: @JimReynolds I agree with your suggestion about personification, but as your example below shows, the personified object often has an entity quality about it, rather than a vague abstraction. But I agree no hard and fast.

Comment: Well, and whether it's a "good" piece of text, or how well it "works" as a phrase is a separate question from *Can I use it this way?* I didn't mean to imply that I think arming gentrification with a blade the best way to express the intended idea. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it that way, and I expect the intended meaning would be understood by people who can handle somewhat sophisticated language. Whether it's a particularly felicitous use, I don't want to evaluate.

Here's another example of the expression setting two non-persons against each other:

> And the 1960s counterculture, which fancied itself **at daggers drawn with** the "Establishment," partook of the same central assumption -- that limits, sometimes known as hang-ups or repressions or bourgeois values, were to be ignored, confronted, transcended, abolished.

Date    1996 (Oct)
Publication information Vol. 47 Issue 6, p54, 4p
Title   The legacy of the sixties.
Author  Will, George F.
Source  American Heritage

Located with the [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/)